# How to add Radio Button in columns while rendering Data Grid in React js

Tags: reactjs, datagrid

Is there any way to use radio button instead of checkboxes in react-data-grid component ?

As per my project  requirement , I can only edit a single Row at a time in DataGrid.

For example : If we have columns, Employee ID and Employee Name in DataGrid, On selecting particular Row a button will be enabled which will direct to a page wherein we could edit the other  details of the selected Employee. At a time, only one Row should be editable.

How can I achieve this?